# Laravel | OrderBy related table's column in half-assembled builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have half-ready Builder instance:

```
$builder = PageLang::with(['page', 'version'])
           ->where('page_id', $_GET['id']) 
           ->groupBy('version_id').
```

And I need to sort the result by page column (URL). The trick is that I need to do with already half-assembled Builder. I can't do it earlier. So how do I do something like that:

`$builder->related('page', function($q) { $q->orderBy... })`

Comment: What is required for you to do after this is done?

Comment: This is important as you may be able to achieve with collection methods rather than builder methods

Comment: @thisiskelvin that's the point, I need to return builder instance. I know about collection methods

Comment: Ok makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$builder = PageLang::join('pages', 'pages.id', '=', 'page_langs.page_id') // you could write your joining columns here
       ->with(['page', 'version'])
       ->where('page_id', $_GET['id']) 
       ->groupBy('version_id')
       ->orderBy('pages.column, 'DESC')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

this would do I suppose. This will be eagerloaded

```
$builder->with('page', function($q) { 
      $q->orderBy... 
});
```

Also instead of `$_GET`, use the `request()` helper function or `$request` object if you have it in the controller method

Comment: doesn't work. Throws error: mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given. 

$builder->with('page', function($q) {
                $q->orderBy('url', 'asc');
            });